# PNG image from PSD seems to be broken

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png, selections

I am not much of a designer. I have been given a PSD file and want to code that using HTML/ CSS. The PSD can be found here (https://www.mediafire.com/file/t6i8jy6kx2fwat5/restaurant.psd/file). I am trying to take the logo from the PSD and use it in my HTML. I generally use the slice tool but since the logo's background is transparent I used the below process.

1. Select the logo layer and press ALT in the eye icon for that layer to deselect all other layers.
2. Image > Trim
3. Save as web, the file format is PNG 8.

The actual logo appears to be pretty crisp in the PSD. When I use it in my code however the logo appears to be broken along its edges . Could any one tell me if I am following the right process to do this ? And why does the logo appear so ugly in my code ?

This is the code to insert the logo . I am using bootsrap :

```
<body>
    <div class = "header-area" style = "background-color:black">
        <div class = "container">
            <div class = "row" >
                <div class = "col-md-2">
                    <img src="assets/img/logo.png">
                </div>
```

[image: PSD Logo]

[image: Logo Broken]

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!

Comment: While you can probably get a much better export than that, I highly recommend just asking for the original source for that logo or an SVG version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PNG-8 only supports single-bit transparency, meaning you can't have 50% transparency and therefore edges can become pixelated.
Use PNG-24 or even better a vector SVG. Image dimensions likely are too small too.